# iPads not showing signs of connection with wireless network

Tags: dhcp, wifi, ipad

I have just started to work for London company which provides iPads for some typs of conferences within UK. Those iPads connect to our own wireless networks and pull out the data from the local server. Yesterday, at one of the events, I noticed a strange thing:

Even though iPads were not indicated as connected to our closed wireless network they were working perfectly fine. The indication I mean are:

- iPad 'network wave' wasn't showing up
- when in network manager there was a circle spinning next to our network (iPads connect to this network automatically)
- network manager were not giving out any details providing by DHCP server

However when logged in to web management console of the access point all ipads were getting ip addresses which might indicate that it just the nature of iPads to behave that way from time to time.

Any ideas why this has happened?

Comment: No and it's unlikely to be our kind of thing on here to be honest, it's a bit of a grey area really as the issue is with the display on the iPads but the actual network/dhcp and server was working. It may get migrated to our sister site superuser.com or one of the other stackoverflow sites.

Comment: What version of iOS?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your input. It's hard to place this question anywhere. Think will go to ask couple of pros I know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Bigbio2002, will let you know soon. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind why there's a spinning circle or no wave in the left top corner of an ipad was the lack of device with assigned 10.0.0.1 in our network. Our DHCP server is set to give gateway of 10.0.0.1 and once we configured one of the laptops to work as a dummy gateway with  this particular IP address, the circle disappeared and wave came back.